# getting a GPA Calculator function to work

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm trying to create a GPA calculator function with the given 9 grades and credits. Why doesn't it work and how do I fix it?

The grades I need to input into the function are `grades <- c(87,93,83,68,75,76,88,93,77)`

```
gpaCalculator <- function(transcript){
    gradePoint <- NULL
    
    gradePoint[transcript > 89.5 & transcript < 100.0] <- 4.0
    gradePoint[transcript > 84.5 & transcript < 89.5] <- 3.5
    gradePoint[transcript > 79.5 & transcript < 84.5] <- 3.0
    gradePoint[transcript > 74.5 & transcript < 79.5] <- 2.5
    gradePoint[transcript > 69.5 & transcript < 74.5] <- 2.0
    gradePoint[transcript > 59.5 & transcript < 69.5] <- 1.0
    gradePoint[transcript > 00.0 & transcript < 59.5] <- 1.0 

    GPA <- sum(credits * gradePoint) / sum(credits)  
    return(GPA)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please post your code and output in a **text format** (cut-and-paste into a code block), rather than as images?

Comment: good start, thanks. Now include the input data and results as well?

Comment: Also, explain what "doesn't work" means ... you might want to pass a `credits` argument along with the `transcript` argument?

Comment: Well that's the thing, this is all I have. I'm confused as to how to implement any input data to get the function to ask for the grades and calculate the gpa.

Comment: OK.  (1) Please edit to include the input data in a text format (then you can delete the image links). (2) "Doesn't work" means "this couldn't possibly work", not "I tried it and got an error/got the wrong answers" ?

Comment: Oh, by "doesn't work" I mean that when I run it, nothing happens due to whatever I'm missing. And sorry I'm new to R so a lot of the coding is not obvious to me

Comment: `credits` is undefined; if you have it defined in the global (or some other) environment, don't do that, it makes things hard to debug and reproduce. Define it in the function and/or pass it explicitly as an argument.