# Why is my GPA Calculator not calculating the GPA correctly?

Tags: r

My GPA Calculator is returning the wrong value (3.47) for the GPA when it should be around 2.98. Can someone please point out the error that is causing this in my code as well as the necessary fix?

```
gpaCalculator <- function(transcript){
gradePoint <- NULL

gradePoint[transcript > 89.5 & transcript < 100.0] <- 4.0
gradePoint[transcript > 84.5 & transcript < 89.5] <- 3.5
gradePoint[transcript > 79.5 & transcript < 84.5] <- 3.0
gradePoint[transcript > 74.5 & transcript < 79.5] <- 2.5
gradePoint[transcript > 69.5 & transcript < 74.5] <- 2.0
gradePoint[transcript > 59.5 & transcript < 69.5] <- 1.0
gradePoint[transcript > 00.0 & transcript < 59.5] <- 0.0

return(GPA)
}

Course <- c("640:135","198:101","198:280","640:237","640:327","198:102","640:136","198:251","198:335")
Grade <- c(87,93,83,68,75,76,88,93,77)
Credits <- c(4,3,3,3,3,3,4,3,3)
transcript <- data.frame(Course,Grade,Credits)
print(transcript)

gpaCalculator(transcript)
```

Comment: Your function is incomplete, you are missing the definition for "GPA" also you need to specify which column in transcript to calculate the grade from.  Start by changing  "transcript" to "transcript$Grade"

Comment: Do I put transcript$Grade for every instance of "transcript" in the entire code or just for where I put gradePoint?

Comment: In the future, please *edit* your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73888605/) by clicking the link under your question rather than post a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few issues:

1. Your function body is written as if it takes a numeric vector of grades as the input, but you are passing in the whole data frame `transcript`. If you want to pass the whole data frame in, then your function needs to extract the `Grade` column. `transcript > 89.5` doesn't make sense when `transcript` is a multi-column data frame. **However**, I think the function probably makes more sense if you pass in the grades as a vector. This will be more flexible, especially if you want to use it with `dplyr` or `data.table`.
2. Your function creates an object named `gradePoint`--sort of, the `gradePoint <- NULL` isn't a great way to initialize, setting it to the right length would be much better. But at the end you have `return(GPA)`, and `GPA` hasn't been mentioned before.
3. Not sure if your grades are always integers. As written, a grade at any of the cutpoints (e.g., *exactly* 89.5, or exactly 100) will not get a grade point because you use `<` and never `<=`.
4. You don't actually calculate an average? Not sure if you want to. You calculate the grade points for each class and return them. Do you want to return the GPA, or just the GP?

Addressing those issues, we can get this:

```
gpCalculator <- function(grades){
  gp <- numeric(length(grades))
  gp[grades > 89.5 & grades <= 100.0] <- 4.0
  gp[grades > 84.5 & grades <= 89.5] <- 3.5
  gp[grades > 79.5 & grades <= 84.5] <- 3.0
  gp[grades > 74.5 & grades <= 79.5] <- 2.5
  gp[grades > 69.5 & grades <= 74.5] <- 2.0
  gp[grades > 59.5 & grades <= 69.5] <- 1.0
  gp[grades > 00.0 & grades <= 59.5] <- 0.0

  return(gp)
}

(gp = gpCalculator(transcript$Grade))
# [1] 3.5 4.0 3.0 1.0 2.5 2.5 3.5 4.0 2.5

mean(gp)
# [1] 2.944444

weighted.mean(gp, w = transcript$Credits)
# [1] 2.982759
```